# SoundCloud app and client_id parameter with PHP

Tags: php, security, soundcloud

I've come across an open source project on GitHub, [SoundCloud-Profile-Backup](https://github.com/onlineth/SoundCloud-Profile-Backup), where the user has developed a web page with some PHP code:

```
require 'secure.php';
//Create a secure.php and set the variable $client_id to your client_id
```

The `$client_id` variable is subsequently used (but never set explicitly in the web page, for what I can see) as a parameter of the [`\resolve`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) resource in the [SoundCloud HTTP API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference).

Here's a fragment of the line where it's used:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/$username&client_id=$client_id
```

Since I'm not familiar with PHP and SoundCloud app development, my questions are:

- The project is open source, but there's no *secure.php* available, so I assume it's somehow part of PHP and not something created ad-hoc. What's *secure.php* then?
- What's the `$client_id` variable exactly? Is it a kind of PHP built-in variable that is set whenever *secure.php* is included, as hinted by the comment?

Comment: I would recommend reading some basic PHP tutorial that tells you what require does. For example [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: @DIDoS Thank you, but my question is not about the `require` statement, I guessed what that is. The project I mentioned is open source, but there's no _secure.php_ available, so I assume it's somehow part of PHP and not something custom.

Comment: Why has this question been voted to close? Why the downvote?

Comment: @mguassa - the comment below the `require` tells you what you need to do - create a file called `secure.php`, and set `$client_id` in that. What the value should be is presumably elsewhere in the docs.

Comment: @andrewsi Thank you, I got it now. Since the project is open source, and _secure.php_ isn't avaialble, I thought I could not have access to it in order to set the `$client_id`.

Comment: I've edited my question after reading the answer that explained what I
wanted to know. I think that my question and the accepted answer could still be **useful to people willing to develop a SoundCloud app with PHP
(there are practical implementation details).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require 'secure.php';` and the `$client_id` variable where used in my app (we spoke on Software Recommendations) and **has nothing to do with SoundCloud or PHP**.

Basically, the idea behind the file `secure.php` and the `$client_id` was to have the credentials for SoundCloud's API in a single file. The file would then be in my `.gitignore` file so it would not be sent off to GitHub. This way I could have the script public and the credentials private.

For information on `require '';`, check out the [Require function on PHP.org](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). Basically, it just makes sure the file given in the parameters loads and if it doesn't, the script errors out.

The `$client_id` is the 32 character ID given by SoundCloud's Developer App Dashboard.

Again, **SoundCloud** and **PHP** have nothing to do with `secure.php` or `$client_id` - it is just used in my app.

Comment: Thank you, it's very kind of you to answer here with **implementation details that might be useful to other people** as well. Since I'm not familiar with PHP, and your project is open source, I assumed, wrongly, that _secure.php_ was part of PHP, and not something custom developed by you. Hence, I didn't know how the
`$client_id` could be set. It all makes sense now!